# How to load an audio/videos into Hbase

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I am looking for how to ingest audio/videos files in HBase.
my videos/audio files are in HDFS and I would like to know how to ingest it in HBase and further how to retrieve it from HBase.

can someone suggest? HBase documentation not contain these details but i have heard it from many webinar that HBase can store audio/video files

Comment: I dont have a solution enough to respond in answer capacity.  That said, I have stored image data in nosql database as the base64 encoded binary.   So this is possible, HOWEVER,  audio and video files could be very big so you need to think about how that is partitioned.